# Spring and Hibernate save not working

Tags: spring, hibernate, struts2

I am using Hibernate and Spring 3.0 i am trying to save the value into database but when i see a console the only select query is showing insert or update is not showing and save is not working

I created a sessionFactory bean and inject it into Impl

```
 <bean id="GetStartedDAOBean" class="com.sample.dao.impl.GetStartedDAOImpl" >
            <property name="sessionfactory" ref="sessionFactory">
            </property>
    </bean

<bean id="GetStartedActionBean" class="com.sample.action.GetStartedAction">
        <property name="getStartedDAOImpl" ref="GetStartedDAOBean"></property>
        <property name="industryDAOImpl" ref="IndustryDAOBean"></property>
        <property name="stateDAOImpl" ref="stateDAOBean"></property>
    </bean>
```

In impl i have

```
private SessionFactory sessionfactory;

      public void setSessionfactory(SessionFactory sessionfactory) {
        this.sessionfactory = sessionfactory;
      }


    public void save(Customer customer)throws IllegalStateException,SystemException{

        try {
            sessionfactory.openSession().saveOrUpdate(customer);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();    
        }

    }
```

when i debug there is value in sessionFactory but it does not save any value. and also does not show any inserted query. There is no error.

Any one can help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You open your session (in-memory) and save something onto it, but the session saves in the database only when you `flush()`. Do a

```
Session session = sessionfactory.openSession();
session.saveOrUpdate(customer);
session.flush();
```

Another way is to commit the transaction, and thus Hibernate will automatically call `flush()`.

Answer (score 4):

Try with `@Transactional` at the method, and add the following to your XML:

```xml
<tx:annotation-driven/>
```

Comment: where i have to give @Transactional

Comment: where you are calling save() method

Answer (score -1):

`@Transaction` you have give on method of service class and `<tx:annotation-driven/>` you have to give in `applicaiton-context.xml` file.

Hence, when any one call the service class's method, the transaciton will start by spring and it will handle up to commit and rollback.

Comment: This is identical to PSR's answer.

Comment: correct, but in that addition i have mentioned that @Transactionl have to put on service class.

Comment: It should be "@Transactional" and "application-context". Also, you've merely duplicated PSR's answer.